# Android: Close dialog webview upon form submission response

Tags: android

I have a webview containing a form which has both send and cancel buttons. The webview opens in a dialog and I'd like this to close upon either successful form submission or cancellation.  The buttons are part of the webview's HTML.  The form exists on a third party server that I have no control over.  The send button reloads the parent page, and the cancel button closes the form on the originating site.  I'm using an HTML parser to display just the form and buttons.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WebViewClient rclient = new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView  view, String  url){
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onLoadResource(WebView  view, String  url){
        finish();
        }

};
webview.setWebViewClient(rclient);
```

This seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
/**
 * Custom web client to let us override behaviour when the edit form has been submitted
 */
private WebViewClient getWebviewClient() {
    return new WebViewClient() {

        /**
         * let's finish this activity once the form has been saved and a message has been display
         */
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            if (url.contains(DONE_URL)) {
                displayDialogToFinishActivity();
            }
        }
    };
}
```